# How to make URL change upon clicking through AJAX loaded menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, url

I've been following a video tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytKc0QsVRY4 ) on how to create a website that loads menus through AJAX. This is great, except I'd like the URLs to change so that the user has something to link to, and can also use the back and forward buttons on their browser properly.

How can this be achieved (hopefully so that it's compatible with what I've already been working on)?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/ru8potv4/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
    <script></script>

</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-color: aqua;
}

ul#nav {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

ul#nav li {
    display:inline;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //initial
    $('#content').load('content/index.php');

    //handle menu clicks
    $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change so that the user has something to link to"?

Comment: You're looking for the history API.

Comment: _change so that the user has something to link to_ saying this are you trying to give functionality to display user that particular specified `view`, which is loaded through `ajax`, when `url` is pasted or clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a hash(#) to the page url with user clicks on any link.. Check url hash on page load and on hashchange event.... then load respective page on that.

This way you can have unique url for each page and also browser back and forth buttons will work perfectly.

note: javascript hashchange event might not work in few older browser versions, so you might want to try any plugins available for that.